# Type style in css is producing BOLD results

Tags: php, css

I'm sure this is a simple css question but I'm stumped? - My H3 tag is producing bold text and I want in normal. page source is not indicating `<B>` tag present, but the text is clearly BOLD. I do want my H2 tag to be bold but currently not set in css since results are already bold.

```
<?php
include_once ( "/home/miemss5/public_html/wp-blog-header.php" );

global $current_user;

$FName = $current_user->user_firstname;
$LName = $current_user->user_lastname;
$FullName = $current_user->display_name;
?>  

<HTML>
<HEAD>

<TITLE>Certificate</TITLE>

<SCRIPT>
var strTitle = "MDERS Test";
var g_arrMonths = new Array()

// Enter the month names below
try
{
g_arrMonths[0] = __MONTH_JAN__; 
g_arrMonths[1] = __MONTH_FEB__;
g_arrMonths[2] = __MONTH_MAR__;
g_arrMonths[3] = __MONTH_APR__;
g_arrMonths[4] = __MONTH_MAY__;
g_arrMonths[5] = __MONTH_JUN__;
g_arrMonths[6] = __MONTH_JUL__;
g_arrMonths[7] = __MONTH_AUG__;
g_arrMonths[8] = __MONTH_SEP__;
g_arrMonths[9] = __MONTH_OCT__;
g_arrMonths[10] = __MONTH_NOV__;
g_arrMonths[11] = __MONTH_DEC__;

// Enter the column headers
var g_strDateTime       = __DATE_TIME__;
var g_strStudentScore   = __STUDENT_SCORE__;
var g_strPassingScore   = __PASSING_SCORE__;
var g_strResult1        = __RESULT__;
var g_strQuestion       = __QUESTION__;
var g_strCorrectAns     = __CORRECT_ANS__;
var g_strResult2        = __RESULT__;
var g_strStudentAns     = __STUDENT_ANS__;
var g_strPointsAwarded  = __POINTS_AWARD__;
var g_strNeutral        = __NEUTRAL__;
var g_strCorrect        = __CORRECT__;
var g_strIncorrect      = __INCORRECT__;
}
catch(e)
{
g_arrMonths[0] = "January"; 
g_arrMonths[1] = "February";
g_arrMonths[2] = "March";
g_arrMonths[3] = "April";
g_arrMonths[4] = "May";
g_arrMonths[5] = "June";
g_arrMonths[6] = "July";
g_arrMonths[7] = "August";
g_arrMonths[8] = "September";
g_arrMonths[9] = "October";
g_arrMonths[10] = "November";
g_arrMonths[11] = "December";

// Enter the column headers
var g_strDateTime = "Date / Time";
var g_strStudentScore = "Student Score";
var g_strPassingScore = "Passing Score";
var g_strResult1 = "Result";
var g_strQuestion = "Question";
var g_strCorrectAns = "Correct Answer";
var g_strResult2 = "Result";
var g_strStudentAns = "Student Answer";
var g_strPointsAwarded = "Points Awarded";
var g_strNeutral = "Neutral";
var g_strCorrect = "Correct";
var g_strIncorrect = "Incorrect";
}
</SCRIPT>

<STYLE>

TD {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
width: 12.5%;
}

.CORRECT {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
color: #008800;
}

.INCORRECT {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
color: #880000;
}

.NEUTRAL {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
color: #000088;
}

.QUESTION {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: left;
width: 46.25%;  
}

.NUMBER {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
width: 3.75%;
}

.DATE {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;

}

.DATETIME {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.SUMMARY {
font-size:10pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
}

H1 {
font-size:14pt;
font-family:arial;
text-align: center;
}

TH {
font-size:12pt;
font-family:arial;
}

.image { 
position: relative; 
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

H2 {
font-size:40pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
text-align: center;
position: absolute; 
top: 150px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
}

H3 {
font-size:32pt;
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
text-align: center;
position: absolute; 
top: 210px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
}

</STYLE>

<SCRIPT>
var g_oContentResults = window.opener.g_oContentResults;
var g_listQuizzes = window.opener.g_listQuizzes;
var g_oPrintOptions = window.opener.g_oPrintOptions;


function FormatDate(dtmDate)
{
var strResult = "";
var nHours = dtmDate.getHours();
var strAM = "am";
var nMinutes = dtmDate.getMinutes();
var strMinutes = "" + nMinutes;

if (nMinutes < 10)
{
    strMinutes = "0" + nMinutes;
}

if (nHours == 12)
{
    strAM = "pm";
}

if (nHours > 12)
{
    nHours -= 12;
    strAM = "pm";
}


strResult += "<P>"
strResult += g_arrMonths[dtmDate.getMonth()] + " ";
strResult += dtmDate.getDate() + ", ";
strResult += dtmDate.getFullYear() + "  ";
strResult += nHours + ":";
strResult += strMinutes + " ";
strResult += strAM;
strResult += "</P>"
return strResult;
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<center>
    <img src="../quizimages/cert.jpg">
</center>
<p>

<SCRIPT>

var namedata = <?php echo json_encode($current_user->user_firstname . '  ' . $current_user->user_lastname); ?>;


    document.write("<H2>Certificate of Completion</H2></br></br>");
    document.write("<H3>This Certifies That</br>");
    document.write("" + "John Doe" + "</br>");
    //document.write("" + namedata + "</br>");
    document.write("Has Successfully Completed The</br>");
    //document.write("" + strTitle + "</br></br>");
    document.write("<I>" + "Maryland Triage System Course" + "</I></H3></br>");
    document.write("</br></br>");
    document.write( FormatDate(g_oContentResults.dtmFinished));
    document.write("Score: " + g_listQuizzes[g_oPrintOptions.strMainQuizId].nPtScore + "</br></br>" );      
    document.write('<center> <input type=button onClick="window.print()" value="Print This Page"/> </center>');

</SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Heading tags are bold by *default*...have you overriden this at all?

Comment: no - i know very little about css

Comment: That's coming from the browsers default styling when you haven't applied any CSS to your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading tags are bold by default...just override it.

```css
.normal {
  font-weight:normal;
  }
```

```html
<h3>DEFAULT</h3>

<h3 class="normal">NORMAL</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was something simple.